# Error in solving isoperimetric problem with first integral formulation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

In order to solve the isoperimetric problem, I am extremising the functional:

$$A[x,y] = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(x \dot y - y \dot x) \;dt\tag{1}$$

where $x = x(t)$, $y = y(t)$, and the Lagrangian is:

$$f = \frac{1}{2}(x \dot y - y \dot x) - \lambda\sqrt{\dot x^2 + \dot y^2}. \tag{2}
$$

I have already successfully solved the problem using the standard Euler-Lagrange equations, which give the parametric equations for a circle with radius $r = \lambda$. This time, I was trying to use the following first integral, which is applicable since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0.$

$$f -  \dot x \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x} - \dot y \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y} = K.\tag{3} 
$$

Evaluating this seems to give $K = 0$. However, plugging in the solution curves for perimeter $2\pi r$,

$$x(t) = r\cos(t)\tag{4}$$
$$y(t) = r\sin(t)$$

gives:

$$f = \frac{r^2}{2} - r\lambda\tag{5}$$

$$\implies \dot x \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x}, \;\;\dot y \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y} = 0 \tag{6}$$

$$\implies f \equiv 0 \implies \lambda = \frac{r}{2}\tag{7}$$

I have been staring at this for a long time, but I can't find the error. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Can you tell us what Dido's problem is?

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry, I meant the [isoperimetric problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality), which is closely related to but not the same as Dido's problem. It is the problem of maximising the area bounded by a simple curve of fixed length in the plane. The solution is the circle which has the given length as its circumference.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, there are several issues with OP's method:

1. In eq. (2) the square root term should in principle be replaced by the full perimeter constraint, not just part of it.
2. In eq. (6) it does not make sense to partial differentiate the Lagrangian (2) wrt. $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ after it has been evaluated (5) on the solution (4).

Boths issues can be remedied relatively easy.

Comment: Hello, I'm OP. 1. Good observation -- we have generally neglected it in lectures since it always vanishes. However, putting it in gives $\frac{r^2}{2} - r\lambda - 2\pi r \lambda $, which makes the problem "even worse", so I guess the main problem is 2. Thus moving on to 2. -- why not?